# when i use “output.name[0]="Tjoint” there is a error Segmentation fault

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The code is as follows:

```
#include "ros/ros.h"
#include "std_msgs/String.h"
#include "sensor_msgs/JointState.h" 
#include <sstream>

class SubscribeAndPublish
{
public:
    SubscribeAndPublish()
        {
            //topic you want to publish
            pub_=n.advertise<sensor_msgs::JointState>("/arm/joint_states",1000);
            //subscribe
            sub_=n.subscribe("/joint_states",1000,&SubscribeAndPublish::callback,this);
        }
    
    void callback(const sensor_msgs::JointState::ConstPtr& msg)
        {
            sensor_msgs::JointState output;
            output.name=msg->name;  //  output.name[0]="Tjoint
            output.position=msg->position;
            output.header=msg->header;
            pub_.publish(output);
        }
   
private:
    ros::NodeHandle n;
    ros::Publisher pub_;
    ros::Subscriber sub_;
};

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    ros::init(argc, argv, "talker");
    SubscribeAndPublish SAPobject;
   
    ros::spin();
   
    return 0;
}
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/260937/when-i-use-%E2%80%9Coutput.name%5B0%5D=%22tjoint%E2%80%9D----there-is-a-error--segmentation-fault/) by [buaawanggg](https://answers.ros.org/users/30181/buaawanggg/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2017-05-03

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-05-03**:
This is not a question.

Please format your code properly (use the *Preformatted text* button) and explain what you are trying to do, what doesn't work and why you think that doesn't work.

**Comment by [buaawanggg](https://answers.ros.org/users/30181/buaawanggg/) on 2017-05-03**:
thx for your advice ，i try to write a node to subscribe the topic “joint-states” ，  this topic have messages of 6 joints ，but what i need is only the message of “joint0” and publish the message of “joint0” to topic “arm/joint_states”

**Comment by [buaawanggg](https://answers.ros.org/users/30181/buaawanggg/) on 2017-05-03**:
i want to use the  “void  callback“” to filter the message

**Comment by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) on 2017-05-04**:
I've provided an answer to your question, and reformatted your original question. I was only able to do this because I had already answered your original question; so I knew what you were asking. As @gvdhoorn indicated, please put more effort into writing clear and nicely formatted questions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can't call `output.name[0]` without first allocating at least one entry in the `std::vector<std::string>` data that is the `output.name` field. You should likely use something like [std::vector::push_back](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/push_back/) or [std::vector::resize](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/resize/) to allocate the memory. The same is true for the position field.

Here's a quick rewrite of your callback as an example:

```
void callback(const sensor_msgs::JointState::ConstPtr& msg)
{
    sensor_msgs::JointState output;
    output.header = msg->header;
    // create space for our single joint name and position:
    output.name.resize(1);
    output.position.resize(1);
    // find correct joint and store in output:
    std::vector<std::string>::const_iterator name_it = msg->name.begin();
    std::vector<double>::const_iterator position_it = msg->position.begin();
    for (; name_it != msg->name.end() && position_it != msg->position.end(); ++name_it, ++position_it)
    {
        if ( (*name_it).compare("joint1") == 0)
        {
            // then we've found the joint!
            output.name[0] = *name_it;
            output.position[0] = *position_it;
            pub_.publish(output);
            break;
        }
    }
    return;
}
```

---

Originally posted by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) with karma: 9031 on 2017-05-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0